# set infinite timeout period in mysql(xampp)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench, mysql

I have 500 MB of mysql tabel which i have to import on my local machine but always it showing the mysql timeout message while importing  the table.

Using Xampp,

thanks,

Comment: Do you mean the PHP timeout? Are you using phpmyadmin for the import? Please add more details, thanks

Comment: Hi I am using xampp phpmyadmin to import the table in my database

Comment: Have a look at [bigdump](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/)

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Xampp then you use PhPMyAdmin.

This is a free software done with php, it has 60 seconds of run time.

You can either try to upgrade the seconds run for php scripts or you can install a specific software, like Mysql WorkBench or similar.

Comment: phpmyadmin won't import files over 500MB

Comment: I didn't even knew that limit o_o well, i suppose he needs to change it's db management program to succesfully import those data.